# Problem using SQLite Trigger to increment a value

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, triggers, sql-insert

Hi guys i'm new in triggers. I have two tables and i want when add a user that works in an department the value of employees to increase by one in the particular department. But i take an error like "Error while committing new row: No such column user.department_id.

```
CREATE TABLE department (
   department_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   department_name TEXT    NOT NULL,
   employees       INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user (
user_id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
user_name     TEXT    NOT NULL,
department_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (
    department_id
)
REFERENCES department (department_id)
```

);

```
CREATE TRIGGER inputUser
     AFTER INSERT
        ON user
BEGIN
    UPDATE department
       SET employees = employees + 1
     WHERE department.department_id = user.department_id;
END;

INSERT INTO user(user_id, user_name, department_id) VALUES(1, "Testuser", 1);
```

Any help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the trigger, you can use [pseudo-tables `new` or  `old`] to refer to the row that is being modified:

```
UPDATE department
   SET employees = employees + 1
WHERE department.department_id = new.department_id;
```

Here is a **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f33bbda2cdc4f9d446437c73b89a603c)**.

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally problem solved